# Palabra o expresión para designar a los celos por el hermano pequeño

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Cuando llega un nuevo miembro a una familia es normal que, si ya hay un hijo previo, este sienta celos del hermano menor, y su comportamiento cambie para hacerse notar un poco más, o tratar de llamar la atención ante el miedo a que los padres empiecen a echarle más cuenta al menor que a él. Este cambio de comportamiento puede (o no) incluir un empeoramiento de la conducta.

¿Existe alguna palabra más técnica, ya sea en la RAE o terminología médica, para expresar este tipo concreto de celos?

Comment: Esta pregunta está basada en hechos reales. :-)

Comment: [_El príncipe destronado_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_pr%C3%ADncipe_destronado) :) ¡¡¡Felicidades si es porque ha aumentado tu prole!!!

Comment: @fedorqui ¿por qué no lo pones como respuesta? Es así como lo llaman en psicología infantil: síndrome del príncipe destronado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece ser que existe el ***síndrome del príncipe destronado*** para referirse a este fenómeno.

Tal y como explica un [artículo de Mapfre](https://www.salud.mapfre.es/salud-familiar/ninos/psicologia-infantil/sindrome-del-principe-destronado/):

> El nacimiento de un hermano puede provocar en el niño el llamado ‘síndrome del príncipe destronado’, es decir, la aparición de celos hacia el hermano recién llegado. Cualquier cambio en la estructura de una familia implica a la vez la necesidad de introducir ajustes y entre ellos se encuentran la repartición del tiempo, los cuidados y las atenciones hacia ambos hermanos, que hasta el momento no había sido necesaria. principe destronadoEsta nueva situación implica pasar de recibir toda la atención de los padres a tener que compartirla con el hermano, a la vez que pasar a ser el hermano mayor en lugar del único niño de la casa.

No he encontrado referencias oficiales, pero sí muchas entradas en páginas y foros de padres y madres. En algunas también se menciona el *síndrome del rey destronado* (no confundir con el [síndrome de Reye](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%ADndrome_de_Reye)).

Y al hilo de la última referencia, también he encontrado el [síndrome del emperador o del niño tirano](http://www.siquia.com/2013/10/sindrome-del-emperador-o-del-nino-tirano-como-detectarlo/):

> El síndrome del emperador, del niño tirano o del niño rey son los distintos nombres con que se conoce a un fenómeno cada vez más común: el de los niños que acaban por dominar a sus padres, e incluso, en los casos más extremos, por maltratarles.

Comment: He encontrado que lo llaman también _complejo de Caín_: 

«El psicólogo francés Charles Badouin, el primero en usar el término escribe: "El niño al que le cabe en suerte un hermanito o una hermanita, reacciona primero, muy generalmente, con unos celos desmedidos y de carácter completamente animal, que subsisten luego, latentes y más o menos bien reprimidos. La hostilidad del menor frente al mayor aparece como una réplica natural a dicha hostilidad".»